# Swift revert .hash?

Tags: swift, hash

I hashed a string:

let TestString = String("Test".hash)

How can I revert the hash to get back my word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Hashing is a one-way operation; it's possible for multiple strings to end up with the same hash value.